# Unobtrusive way to do $(document).ready(.....) in rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

In one of my views I need to do something upon loading of the page (load google maps JS and then initialize some of my stuff)
I can certainly embed this bit into my haml/erb template but is there an UJS way to do this properly?

```
-content_for :head do
  = google_loader_tag  

#map_canvas

:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    google.load('maps', '3', {other_params:'sensor=false', callback: initialize});
  });
```

I did think that UJS meant not mixing Javascript and html templates together, but here I see no other option. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as Confusion said in comments - it is UJS way

i would add that it's good practice to have such stuff inside `content_for :document_ready` and then `yield :document_ready` at the bottom of your `<body>` tag in your application layout

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't show an example of 'obtrusive javascript'. As such, this *is* the UJS way of doing it.

Comment: I did think that UJS meant not mixing Javascript and html templates together, but here I see no other option. I added this into the question description